# Facebook login Error: Cant load URL

Tags: codeigniter, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-login

[image]

[image]

I have this facebook app and I have setup my client id and secret on the code. When I try to access the api I get this error. I have tried everything. The app domain is localhost and the website url is the path that the app is running. Anyone know how to solve the issue?

This is the request:
https://www.facebook.com/v2.8/dialog/oauth?client_id=266389393769834&state=xxxxx&response_type=code&sdk=php-sdk-5.0.0&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2F%5B%3A%3A1%5D%2Fdemo%2F%2Fuser_authentication&scope=email

Comment: instead of using localhost as domain, I created on my local server an alias lets say de.mo, Then the siteurl would be http://de.mo/demo/user_authentication, which works for me

Comment: @Vickel The URL contains invalid domain would be the response on Facebook

Comment: I've it set as a test app

Comment: @Vickel setting a test app fixed the issue. Thank you!

Comment: I've made my comments an answer... great it worked out...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to test a localhost FB login setup, you cannot use their "Production" setup, as this points to an existing website, or IP

localhost, 127.0.0.1 or any alias (for example: my.domain or de.mo) you set on your localhost server will not work when the FB settings is pointing at production environment.

You need to set up a test environment using FB "Create New App"